# LaunchControl for Mac giving me errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, launchd, launch-daemon

I've been trying to schedule a Python script running with LaunchControl for Mac. My script contains f strings, new in Python 3.6.

For some reason, my I keep getting a syntax error on the f strings, and nothing will run.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include the code that's giving you the syntax error (preferably as a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in your question, so that we can take a look at it.